# How to fix assosiate array key missing in flutter on api response?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `Back-end` created using `Laravel` and when I get response from my `API` request, keys with `URL` will be dropped/missing.

I've tested this with `Front-end`, `Postman` and etc., and working but when I get the response in `Flutter` application, keys will be missing.

Here's an example of the correct response, which I get in `Front-end`, `Postman` and etc. :

```
"businessLinks": [
   {
       "linkTitle": "dsadasdasd",
       "linkUrl": "https://example.com/examples/7465f64a-b55b-4a2c-99da-69595a430694/detail" 
   }
],
```

And Here's the example of what I get when I call the same API request in Flutter

```
"businessLinks": [
   {
       "linkTitle": "dsadasdasd",
       "https://example.com/examples/7465f64a-b55b-4a2c-99da-69595a430694/detail" 
   }
],
```

It's always dropping keys of `URL`, I've tested this in other requests and same thing happened again.

Then only way that I can keep the key is to using an array to get the key, but the value will be an array of one link.

Another thing is that, I didn't printed above responses, they're printed when API call requested in `run` tab in `Android studio`, so no hands on this from me, It's just the `Retrofit` doings.

Here's the flutter setup :

```
Dio :
const String CONTENT_TYPE = "content-type";
const String APPLICATION_JSON = "application/json";
const String ACCEPT = "accept";
const String AUTHORIZATION = "authorization";
const String IDENTIFIER = "identifier";
const String DEV_IDENTIFIER = "devIdentifier";
const String DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = "language";

class DioFactory{
  AppPreferences _appPreferences;
  DioFactory(this._appPreferences);

  Future<Dio> getDio() async {

    Dio dio = Dio();

    int _timeOut = 60 * 1000;

    String language = await _appPreferences.getAppLanguage();
    String identifier = await _appPreferences.getUserIdentifier();
    String devIdentifier = await _appPreferences.getUserDevIdentifier();
    String token = await _appPreferences.getUserToken();

    if(identifier.isEmpty) {
      _appPreferences.setUserIdentifier();
      identifier = await _appPreferences.getUserIdentifier();
    }
    if(devIdentifier.isEmpty) {
      _appPreferences.setUserDevIdentifier();
      devIdentifier = await _appPreferences.getUserDevIdentifier();
    }
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      CONTENT_TYPE: APPLICATION_JSON,
      ACCEPT: APPLICATION_JSON,
      IDENTIFIER: identifier,
      DEV_IDENTIFIER: devIdentifier,
      DEFAULT_LANGUAGE: language
    };

    if(token.isNotEmpty) {
      headers[AUTHORIZATION] = 'Bearer '+token;
    }

    dio.options = BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: Constant.baseUrl,
      connectTimeout: _timeOut,
      receiveTimeout: _timeOut,
      headers: headers
    );

    if(kReleaseMode) {
      print('release mode no logs');
    } else {
      dio.interceptors.add(PrettyDioLogger(
        requestHeader: true, requestBody: true, responseHeader: true
      ));
    }

    return dio;
  }
}
```

```
Api

@RestApi(baseUrl: Constant.baseUrl)
abstract class AppServiceClient {
  factory AppServiceClient(Dio dio, {String baseUrl}) = _AppServiceClient;

  @GET("/mobile/examples/detail/{exampleId}")
  Future<ServiceExampleDetailResponse> getExampleDetail(@Path("exampleId") String exampleId);
}
```

```
Response 
@JsonSerializable()
class ServiceExampleDetailResponse extends BaseResponse {
  @JsonKey(name: "example")
  ExampleDetailResponse example;

  ExampleDetailResponse(this.example);

  factory ServiceExampleDetailResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ServiceExampleDetailResponseFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ExampleDetailResponseToJson(this);

}
```

I can share more codes if needed, but I didn't because It's `MVVM DDD DI REPOSITORY` project so a lots of codes are written and it might get question with full of codes.

Above code is working, I can get my data, I can show data in UI, but the only problem is dropped/missing key.

Project DNA :

```
retrofit: ^3.3.1
dio: ^4.0.6
analyzer: ^4.7.0
json_serializable: ^6.1.5
get_it: ^7.2.0

retrofit_generator: ^4.2.0
build_runner: ^2.1.8
flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.11.0"

Flutter 3.3.5 • channel stable
Tools • Dart 2.18.2 • DevTools 2.15.0
```

Edit 01 :

Here's the responses:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class ExampleDetailResponse {
  @JsonKey(name: "exampleName")
  String exampleName;

  @JsonKey(name: "exampleLinks")
  List<ExamplLinksResponse> exampleLinks;

  @JsonKey(name: "exampleBanners")
  ImageDataResponse exampleBanners;


  ExampleDetailResponse (this.businessName,
      this.businessLinks,
      this.businessBanner);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ExampleDetailResponseToJson(this);

  factory ExampleDetailResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ExampleDetailResponseFromJson(json);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class ExamplLinksResponse{
  @JsonKey(name: "linkTitle")
  String linkTitle;
  @JsonKey(name: "linkUrl")
  String linkUrl;


  ExamplLinksResponse(this.linkTitle, this.linkUrl);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ExamplLinksResponseToJson(this);

  factory ExamplLinksResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ExamplLinksResponseFromJson(json);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class ImageDataResponse {
  @JsonKey(name: "low")
  String low;
  @JsonKey(name: "normal")
  String normal;


  ImageDataResponse(this.low, this.normal);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ImageDataResponseToJson(this);

  factory ImageDataResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ImageDataResponseFromJson(json);
}
```

Changing keys name, doesn't make any difference, since in top example, `ImageData` is getting low and normal image links and both keys will be dropped.

Update : 01

So here's something that I'm faced an I'll update the question base on tests :

in normal URLs, keys won't drop, like : [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) or google.com

But in below something else is happening :

```
I/flutter ( 7893): ║   "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-898
I/flutter ( 7893): ║   6-ee98adf5b9c8/images/_banner_3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8_low.jpe
I/flutter ( 7893): ║   g"
```

As you can see It's going to next line in middle of URL, now I'll try to split above URL from back-end to see the result in front-end.

Now I've separated parts of URL to pieces and as you can see in below, after examples key, rest of keys will be dropped, and it might be because of uuid or the structure of uuid.

Separeted URL in back-end to response:

```
"completed" => "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8/images/_banner_3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8_low.jpeg",
"baseURL" => "https://cdn.example.ir",
"publicImages" => "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images",
"examples" => "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples",
"examplesId" => "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8",
"image" => "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8/image",
"banner" => "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8/image/_banner_",
"bannerId" => "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8/image/_banner_3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8_low",
"full" => "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8/images/_banner_3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8_low.jpeg",
```

=> Result in Flutter

```
I/flutter ( 7893): ║                 "https://cdn.the-hooray.ir/public_images/businesses/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-898
I/flutter ( 7893): ║                 6-ee98adf5b9c8/images/_banner_3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8_low.jpe
I/flutter ( 7893): ║                 g"
I/flutter ( 7893): ║                 "https://cdn.the-hooray.ir/public_images/businesses/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-898
I/flutter ( 7893): ║                 6-ee98adf5b9c8/images/_banner_3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8.jpeg"
I/flutter ( 7893): ║                 "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee9
I/flutter ( 7893): ║                 8adf5b9c8/images/_banner_3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8_low.jpeg"
I/flutter ( 7893): ║                 baseURL: "https://cdn.example.ir",
I/flutter ( 7893): ║                 publicImages: "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images",
I/flutter ( 7893): ║                 examples: "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples",
I/flutter ( 7893): ║                 "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee9
I/flutter ( 7893): ║                 8adf5b9c8"
I/flutter ( 7893): ║                 "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee9
I/flutter ( 7893): ║                 8adf5b9c8/image"
I/flutter ( 7893): ║                 "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee9
I/flutter ( 7893): ║                 8adf5b9c8/image/_banner_"
I/flutter ( 7893): ║                 "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee9
I/flutter ( 7893): ║                 8adf5b9c8/image/_banner_3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8_low"
I/flutter ( 7893): ║                 "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee9
I/flutter ( 7893): ║                 8adf5b9c8/images/_banner_3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8_low.jpeg"

Feels like it's separating full links with UUIDs, dropping their keys and etc. It might be the structure, hyphens or...
```

Updated 02 : I've updated retrofit, dio, and all libraries related to retrofit and still no help...

Update 03 : So after multiple tests I've found out the problem is with URL length, but still no solution on why It is dropping the keys

```
https://cdn.example.ir/publicimagespublicimagespublicimages => key dropped
https://cdn.example.ir/publicimagespublicimagespublic => key exist
https://cdn.example.ir/publicimagespublicimagespublicim => key exist
https://cdn.example.ir/publicimagespublicimagespublicima => key dropped
```

Comment: Can you add `ExampleDetailResponse ` class? Have you changed `linkUrl` key to another name?

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak I've updated then answer. Changing keys name, doesn't make any difference, since in top example, ImageData is getting low and normal image links and both keys will be dropped.

Comment: I've never faced any issues for url's key using retrofit. I think your code is okay. Is `:` after https of the url value is the problem?. Yes, key and value are separated by `:`, but this is strange. You can check it by adding `:` on the `linkTitle` value like  `dsada:sdasd`. If the key is not dropped, the problem is not `:`. PrettyDioLogger problems?

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak I've done some tests and I've updated question, please check after Update 01.

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak Every result I've copied here are part of Pretty Dio Logger Logs, from body.

Comment: Can you try adding `curl_logger_dio_interceptor` as dependency? This will get you curl command for the url flutter is making. Once you get that, let me know here if response from curl command is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried reading the source code of pretty_dio_logger and found out that it clips the response in case the line length goes above line width.

You can find the refer https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/pretty_dio_logger/blob/f1ab4e4ff39b755c56a38d1daff335bcec0bb28f/lib/pretty_dio_logger.dart#L236

I tried testing on my machine and did following:

```dart
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pretty_dio_logger/pretty_dio_logger.dart';

void main() async {
  final dio = Dio();
  dio.interceptors.add(PrettyDioLogger());

  final response =
      await dio.get('https://mocki.io/v1/62377d93-7359-42c0-b8cd-c721f62f2501');

  print(
      "======================================================================");
  print("actual response");

  print(response);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const SizedBox.shrink();
  }
}
```

Output was

```
Reload already in progress, ignoring request
Restarted application in 943ms.
╔╣ Request ║ GET
║  https://mocki.io/v1/62377d93-7359-42c0-b8cd-c721f62f2501
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
╔╣ Response ║ GET ║ Status: 200
║  https://mocki.io/v1/62377d93-7359-42c0-b8cd-c721f62f2501
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
╔ Body
║
║    {
║         "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c
║         8/images/_banner_3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8_low.jpeg"
║         baseURL: "https://cdn.example.ir",
║         publicImages: "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images",
║         examples: "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples",
║         "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c
║         8"
║         "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c
║         8/image"
║         "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c
║         8/image/_banner_"
║         "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c
║         8/image/_banner_3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8_low"
║         "https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c
║         8/images/_banner_3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8_low.jpeg"
║    }
║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
======================================================================
actual response
{"completed":"https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8/images/_banner_3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8_low.jpeg","baseURL":"https://cdn.example.ir","publicImages":"https://cdn.example.ir/public_images","examples":"https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples","examplesId":"https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8","image":"https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8/image","banner":"https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8/image/_banner_","bannerId":"https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8/image/_banner_3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8_low","full":"https://cdn.example.ir/public_images/examples/3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8/images/_banner_3fb9acda-f377-4cfe-8986-ee98adf5b9c8_low.jpeg"}
```

Here you can see that the response has those keys but pretty-printed log doesn't have it. If you increase the maxWidth while defining the PrettyDioLogger, you will get keys in pretty response.
`PrettyDioLogger(maxWidth: 500)`

Comment: Worked. Well i think the issues with URLs in this case is because, there's no space in string and due to no space, it will clip string bcs of maxWidth with default value, which it was 90.